# Where is the location for sweetalert2?

Tags: laravel, sweetalert2

I am having a hard time installing the swwetalert2 package.

npm i sweetalert2 - its fine.
the package is inside node_modules.

inside my app.css i tried different variation of the @import

```
@import '/sweetalert2';

@import '~sweetalert2';
@import 'sweetalert2/dist';
```

but every time I run npm run dev or production I get this:

ERROR in ./resources/css/app.css
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/index.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
Error: Failed to find 'sweetalert2'

no matter the variation I use for the location.

Comment: https://sweetalert2.github.io/#usage

Comment: I know how to use like that <script src="sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>, but I do not want to use it like that.  I want to be able to use @import and then run npm run dev or npm run production..